# Split network traffic between two nic depending on app?

Tags: networking, firewall, transmission

I'm running a `transmission` daemon. I'd like only its torrent traffic to only go through `eth0` while its RPC traffic, **and** all other network traffic, to only go through `eth1`.

I think I can configure `transmission` to split its traffic like this. How do I also cause other traffic to only use `eth1` without blocking `transmission`'s ability to use `eth0` and without allowing fallback between the nic?

[image: task network]

**Edit:** I think I might be able to use `iptable`'s `owner` module to pull this off since the transmission daemon is running under the dedicated user:group `debian-transmission:debian-transmission`. However, it only works on outgoing packets.

Answer (score 0):

Configure bind-address-ipv4 to eth0's local ip and rpc-bind-address to eth1's local ip in settings.json.